# How to assign values to a multidimensional array in an Access VBA module?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, multidimensional-array

The following tells me there's a compiler error - expected end of statement (on the equal sign).

```
Option Compare Database

Dim myArray(2, 2) As Integer = {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
Dim myArray(2, 2) As Integer
myArray(0, 0) = 10
myArray(0, 1) = 10
myArray(1, 0) = 10
myArray(1, 1) = 10
```

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_CreatingAnArray)

Comment: Hi, Edward! See the problem is that when I try to initialize like either Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}, or
Dim doubles = {1.5, 2, 9.9, 18}, it gives me the same compiler error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim myArray(2,2) as Integer
'Note that it is a 3x3 array
'If you need a 2x2 one then change appropriately :)

myArray(0,0) = 10
myArray(0,1) = 10
...
```

If all are the same "10" then:

```
For i=0 To 2
    For j = 0 To 2
        myArray(i,j) = 10
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hmm I thought myArray(2,2) had 2 elements in each dimension (from 0 to 1 each dimension). But so the only way to assign values to a multidimensional array is using a loop or multiple initializations, then? I was hoping I could assign them all with a single statement

Comment: myArray (1,1) is 2x2 same as myArray(0 to 1, 0 to1)

Comment: or myArray(1 to 2, 7 to 8) is 2x2

Comment: on-liners are less tying, true... I NEVER USE THOSE!

Answer (score -1):

```
dim myArray as Variant

myArray = array(Array(1,2), array(3,4))

debug.print myArray(0)(0) '1
debug.print myArray(0)(1) '2
debug.print myArray(1)(0) '3
debug.print myArray(1)(1) '4
```